# Set mouse focus on current screen's active window

Tags: mouse, focus, synergy

I was using Synergy from Symless. It shares the mouse and keyboard between computers. So it is similar to having secondary or third screen attached to your computer.

The Scenario is: having a laptop and a PC.

- On laptop screen, I do some typing with a text editor (Active window).
- On PC screen, the browser is open (Not fullscreen, but active). Under it, there is music player (Fullscreen, but not active).
- When I move my mouse to laptop screen, the focus is on the text editor (even if the mouse is not hovering on the text editor)
- When I move my mouse to PC screen, the focus is on the browser (even if the mouse is hovering on the music player)

**=> That is the desired behavior, and that is how Synergy works.**

Now I want mimic that behavior with one computer but multiple screens.
I'm using Elementary.

Under Tweak Tool, there is a focus option. The options are `Click` (Change focusing window in click), `Mouse` (Change focusing window by hovering the mouse) and `Sloppy` (Same as Mouse, actually don't know how it is different from `Mouse`).

The nearest I got to mimic the behavior in the scenario is to use `Mouse` focus mode. But you have to move the mouse onto the window you want to focus. This mode is annoying when you open a new window, but the focus is not on that new window because the mouse is off somewhere.

**So what I want is probably `Click` focus mode, but each screen has a different Active Window of itself. When I move my mouse to a screen, the Active Window of that screen should raise up.**

Do anyone happen to know how to achieve what I described? The goal is to unify the work flow. At home I have my laptop and my PC, but at the office I have my laptop and the secondary screen.

So the different setup pause me and sometimes irritating.

---